# How to increase the default timeout on Webview to load URL in Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-webview

I'm currently loading the URL in webview and everything works perfect. However, in poor network condition I'm getting Err: Timedout on webview with in 10 seconds. I would like to increase this time out value to lets say 60 seconds.
Thank you in Advance.
Here is my webview :

'''

```
webView = findViewById(R.id.webview)
        webView?.let { webView ->
            webView.clearCache(true)
            webView.clearFormData()
            webView.clearHistory()
            Log.i(LOG_TAG,"cleared cache & history on webview")
            webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true;
            webView.settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
            webView.settings.allowContentAccess = true;
            webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true;
            webView.webViewClient = MyWebViewClient(this, progressbarView, progressbar)
        }
```

'''

Here is my webview client code:

'''
override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, request: WebResourceRequest?): Boolean {
val url: String = request?.url.toString();
if (Global.isNetworkConnected(this@Orderdetailswebview)){
return checkAndProcessHolsterManagerCall(view, url)
}else{
var networkDialog = NetworkErrorVideoFragment()
networkDialog.show(fragmentManager, "NetworkErrorDialog")
}
return true
}
override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, url: String): Boolean {
return checkAndProcessHolsterManagerCall(view, url)
}
override fun shouldInterceptRequest(view: WebView, request: WebResourceRequest): WebResourceResponse? {
if(fromActivityVal == "ViewTogether") {
return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request)
}else {
return webResponse(request)
}
}
'''

Comment: Can you show me your "MyWebViewClient" - Code?

Answer (score -1):

I think adding these two lines of code will solve your problem:

```
webView?.let { webView ->
    ...
    // Add these two lines of code
    webView.settings.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT_MILLIS)
    webView.settings.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT_MILLIS)
}
```

Replace the value of `TIMEOUT_MILLIS` with the value you need

Comment: These properties don't seem to be available/accessible for android.webkit WebView & WebSettings. So this probably doesn't work or answer the question.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings